# How to set upload images limit in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

how to I validation only 5 images to upload to the server using Codeigniter controller.

Comment: on form submit you can check or count upload images

Comment: You can check size of $_FILES array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put limit in loop, but make sure you images sequance. For example,

```
$fileCounts = sizeof($files['name']);

foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $image) {
    $totalImageIndex = ($key+1);
    if($totalImageIndex <= 5 ) {
        // Image code here
    }   else {
        continue; // It will be in loop but skip the image uploading
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should used simple `count` function like this

```
$count = count($_FILES['file']['size']);
foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)//loop sample to get all images or files
```

for validation images and count you can try this code

```
$count=0;
$valid_types = array("image/jpg","image/png");

foreach ($_FILES['image'] as $file) {
    count++;

    if (!in_array($file['type'], $valid_types))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```